# Web Deploy works with VS2010; fails with VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

With VS 2010 Web Deploy is functional and working without issue. At the same time, Web Deploy from VS 2012 fails, indicating that the server did not respond and suggesting [this link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC).

This notes the following conditions, all of which are fulfilled.

1. You can ping the remote machine
2. That the msdepsvc or wmsvc service is started on the remote server.
3. Your firewall is not blocking incoming connections of your ports on the destination. If you used the default installation, then it would be 80 for `msdepsvc` and 8172 for `wmsvc`

Web Deploy is still functioning for VS2010.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 2):

Clearly an example of not reading all the documentation first. However, for those looking to understand some of the changes here's what I found.

1. VS 2012 uses the Web Deployment Agent Service and NOT the Web Management Service
2. Local deployment is to "http://Your Server/msdeployagentservice" and NOT :8172/msdeploy.axd

For a complete account of the many options [GO HERE!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337.aspx)

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: correction: VS uses WMSVC by default if you specify the server name.  If you specify the protocol to be http (not https), it will switch to using MSDepSvc.  Specifying http is basically the only way to use MSDepSvc within Visual Studio.  Deploying to localhost is an exception to both of these.